# RHEL - GDM could not be initialized

Tags: linux, gdm, display

**Actions before the GDM failure**

I was trying to install *RT tool* in my system. However, the RT tool required *Perl 5.10*. So, I did `yum remove perl` to remove the existing version. While the command was getting executed, I was not able to navigate to any other tab or window. The system was stuck. So, I long pressed the power button and turned it on.

**After Turning ON**

I got the below error messages (Not exactly in the same order, but after trying various options)

- Couldn't start X server on card 0. (I think when I did the `startx` command)
- Xserver not found.
- Install x server or correct GDM configuration and restart GDM.

I tried to do the below command.

```
cp xorg.conf failsafe xorg.conf
```

However, I did not find the file **xorg.conf** file itself. I tried to update the GDM by doing `yum install GDM` after removing GDM. However, I still do not get the display.

I want to bring back the display without having to reinstall the entire OS again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was the unexpected shutdown which triggered the display problem. Since, I had shut it down using long press while the yum remove perl was going on, the transaction had locked some of the files and it was pending.

I did the following commands to bring back the display.

```
yum -complete-transaction --cleanup
package-cleanup -problems
```